# Setting imageview new position after animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Hi i am new to android animation..
I want to update my image to new position after animation but i fail to do so will appreciate any kind of help..(I have a basic left to right and right to left animation)

XML -

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_menu_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_fill" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.17"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_fill"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="My App"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="34dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_fill" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.17"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_fill"
            android:src="@drawable/main_menu_button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.17"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_fill"
            android:src="@drawable/main_menu_button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.17"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_fill"
            android:src="@drawable/main_menu_button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.17"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_fill"
            android:src="@drawable/main_menu_button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.17"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_fill"
            android:src="@drawable/main_menu_button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.17"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_fill" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.17"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>


Java:
package com.example.mainmenuscreen;

import android.location.GpsStatus.Listener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity {
    OnClickListener openListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        final ImageView login = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login);

        final Animation lefttoright = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.lefttoright);
        Animation righttoleft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.righttoleft);

        // login.startAnimation(righttoleft);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login.startAnimation(lefttoright);
            }
        });

        lefttoright.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//               params.topMargin = login.getTop()-100;
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 100, 0);

                login.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Better use RelativeLayout, and call login.requestLayout() after it

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
Animation#setFillAfter
```

[API doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29)

Comment: I changed that to true on the animation file, doesnt seem to work... =(

Comment: Yup, apperantly the problem was at my layout, I changed it from table layout to linear layout and that did the trick